# Nested select in monitoring devices

Tags: c, linux

I am monitoring devices that are newly plugged. I'm using libudev.h to do what i want.

```
while(1){

        ret = select(fd+1, &fds, NULL, NULL, NULL);

        if(ret<0){

            perror("select() failed. Exitting...");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        if (FD_ISSET(fd, &fds)) {

            dev = udev_monitor_receive_device(mon);

            if (dev) {
                printf("New device attached\n");
                printf("   Node: %s\n", udev_device_get_devnode(dev));
                printf("   Action: %s\n", udev_device_get_action(dev));

                udev_device_unref(dev);

                   if(strcmp("/dev/ttyUSB0", udev_device_get_devnode(dev))==0){

                     fd1 = open("/dev/ttyUSB0");
                           if (fd<0) exit(0);
                     FD_SET(fd1, &fds);

                     select(fd1+1, &fds, NULL, NULL, NULL);
                      if (FD_ISSET(fd1))         
 //Read from the serial device and echo back to serial device when data is received

 }

                   }

            }

            else {

                printf("No Device from receive_device(). An error occured.\n");

            }                   
        }
```

Now for example a device is plugged and the node is /dev/ttyUSB0 i need to open it and monitor it's file descriptor. sitting and waiting for data to be available.

```
    fd1 = open("/dev/ttyUSB0");
                               if (fd<0) exit(0);
                         FD_SET(fd1, &fds);

                         select(fd1+1, &fds, NULL, NULL, NULL);
                          if (FD_ISSET(fd1)){

//Read from the serial device and echo back to serial device when data is received
}
```

While monitoring the fd of /dev/ttyUSB0 the first select must continue doing it's job monitoring for devices. How am i supposed to do 2 select at the same time?.. thanks

Comment: I might be wrong, but I think the typical linuxy thing to do is to fork a child and let them worry about the specific device while the parent continues listening for more devices.  Many linux daemons function in this manner.

Comment: Yes and no. Some daemons do this, because it allows the user to restart the master daemon (e.g. when switching to a new version) without interrupting existing connections; however this requires additional logic so the new master process recognizes existing children.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do two `select`s at the same time. The whole point of `select` is that you can wait for events on more than one file descriptor at the same time. You add both file descriptors to your `FD_SET`, call `select`, and then check which one is set using `FD_ISSET`.

Comment: Yes but the thing is Monitoring of devices comes first. So i don't get to open the device "/dev/ttyUSB0" when it has not yet been detected. I open it and use it's fd when it got detected. then i add it to the fd set..

Comment: You need to add all fds to the FD set everytime before you call `select` -- upon return, only those that have activity on them remain in the set.

Comment: Yes but how can i do the FD_SET after select statement. I know that i first need to fill up fd set before select. but this needs to be done because when a device is found i will open it and add it to the fd_set but select has already executed. will that work?.. thanks

Comment: You go back into `select` when you have opened the device, passing both file descriptors. When `select` returns, either FD may be in the returned set; this is what the `FD_ISSET` tests for. So you'd place both `FD_SET` calls first, then `select`, then all the `if(FD_ISSET(...))`. For more file descriptors, just extend from there.

Comment: The first parameter to `select` is the largest of all file descriptors, plus one.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a locking kind of mechanism , as I think.

Continuously probe in one process about the device that is continously probing the device.

And then when it got just signal to the other process and modify the lock variable